# I want To achieve color in a TextView driven by the HexFiend framework. I almost succeeded, but the colours don't render very well. Any suggestion?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, frameworks

I am trying to achieve multi color text in a TextView driven by the [HexFiend](https://github.com/ridiculousfish/HexFiend/) framework. I have succeeded in setting a solid black as a background, but now I would like to achieve multi-colour text. I have studied a lot the HexFiend source code, and I came up with the following code:
I subclassed HFStringEncodingTextRepresenter and I did override basically one method: styleForAttributes:ranges:

```
#import "HFRepresenterStringEncodingTextView.h"
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <HexFiend/HexFiend.h>
#import "HFTextVisualStyleRun.h"

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface SpecialTextRepresenter : HFStringEncodingTextRepresenter

@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END

#import "SpecialTextRepresenter.h"

@implementation SpecialTextRepresenter


- (HFTextVisualStyleRun *)styleForAttributes:(NSSet *)attributes range:(NSRange)range {
    HFTextVisualStyleRun *run = [[HFTextVisualStyleRun alloc] init];
     
    [run setRange:NSMakeRange(0, [self.controller.byteArray length])];
    [run setForegroundColor:[HFColor orangeColor]];
    [run setBackgroundColor:[HFColor blackColor]];

    NSMutableIndexSet *bookmarkExtents = nil;

    if (! bookmarkExtents) bookmarkExtents = [[NSMutableIndexSet alloc] init];
     
    [bookmarkExtents addIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0,[self.controller.byteArray length])];
     
     if (bookmarkExtents) {
         [run setBookmarkExtents:bookmarkExtents];
     }

    return run;
}

@end
```

I was so happy to have found the solution, but unfortunately it does not look so good:

[image]

So far, I was not able to determine why there are those colourful dashed lines between rows. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue that was causing the coloured lines. It has to do with a feature of HexFiend that is called "Bookmarks". It is not needed in this case since we are only interested in the text colours. Hence, the code listed in my question can be simplified:

```
- (HFTextVisualStyleRun *)styleForAttributes:(NSSet *)attributes range:(NSRange)range {

    HFTextVisualStyleRun *run = [[HFTextVisualStyleRun alloc] init];
         
    [run setRange:NSMakeRange(0, [self.controller.byteArray length])];
    [run setForegroundColor:[HFColor orangeColor]];
    [run setBackgroundColor:[HFColor blackColor]];

    return run;
}
```

The result looks good, just like I was expecting:

[image]

Setting one colour is very simple overriding the above method, but another matter is to achieve precise range-based multi-colour. I am trying to achieve that by using this property of the HFRepresenterTextView:

```
@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSArray *styles;
```

This is an array, containing objects of type HFTextVisualStyleRun, the same object that we deal with in the above overridden method. This is tricky because when setting the array, the framework raises an exception if one of the indexes has no attribute assigned. I will complete this answer as soon as I get a clean solution. Thanks